# Finding a node in Asp.Net TreeView

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am trying to find a node in a treeview with `FindNode` mothod, it works but sometimes doesn't and return `null`

```
TreeNode selectedTreeNode = TreeView1.FindNode(strPath);
```

I am passing exactly correct ValuePath to the method. My treeview considerably big and it may be the reason?

When I use the following line, it works but slowdown the performance.

```
 TreeView1.ExpandAll();
```

Can't I use `FindNode` without using `ExpandAll`?

Comment: If its returns null that means node is not find in tree view. It can only happen if you enter incorrect path. Please check you path.

Comment: As I have mentioned I am giving the correct path and node is found on the tree, only thing that the node is not visible in the tree as it is not expanded.